# Implementación correcta del EventHandler

Tags: c#, interop

Estoy trabajando con eventos e intentando eliminar las advertencias para la [correcta declaración de eventos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1009?view=vs-2019). Según varios artículos que he leído primero que se delcara es un delegado que en este caso no tiene parámetros de entrada, después se declara el evento y se dispara. Tambien hay que hacer una suscripción del evento. El problema es que la advertencia que intento eliminar me dice que declare el primer parámetro como objeto llamado sender y el segundo parámetro como EventArgs llamado e. Pero no para resolverlo debo hacer que ambos parámetros sean o hereden del tipo object y EventArgs.

```
    public delegate void BringMainFormToFront();
    public static event BringMainFormToFront BringMainToFrontEvent;
    public static void OnBringMainToFront()
    {
        BringMainToFrontEvent?.Invoke();
    }

    public MainForm()
    {
        BringMainToFrontEvent += BringMainToFront;
    }
```

Comment: y que queres hacer con el evento? porque no veo que hagas nada, ni le pasas nada al evento para esperar y trabajar.

Answer (score -2):

Puedes seguir la siguiente guía : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/event-handling-in-net-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: Las respuestas que solo tienen enlaces son consideradas de baja calidad. Te sugiero leer [answer] e incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí en el sitio. El enlace está bien para ampliar el tema, dejar referencias a la documentación o artículos externos, pero la idea es tener respuestas completas que, el día que lleguen a desaparecer otros sitios, sigan siendo informativas y útiles para los usuarios de StackOverflow.